# Android : isSelected not working first time in ListView

Tags: android, listview

I have a ListView, when I check for a row click "isSelected()" always returns false even if it's been previously selected, the second time I check it returns true.. The ListView needs to be clicked twice in order for "isSelected()" to work... I've seen similar issues on SO but none of the proposed solutions work..

Note: I'm using a custom ListAdapter, that where I am listening for the row click, so I cant use setOnItemClickListener on the Listview

```
row.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(final View v) {

            v.clearFocus();

            if (v.isSelected())
            {
```

As suggested I added a setOnItemClickListener to the Listview, but now it doesn't detect if selected, it always returns false

```
listview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int position,
                                long id) {

            Log.v("myApp", "onItemClick is " + position);

            if (v.isSelected())
            {
                v.setSelected(false);

                Log.v("MyApp", "fiend deselect row " + position);

                v.setBackgroundResource(R.color.default_color);

            } else {
                Log.v("MyApp", "fiend click row " + position);

                v.setSelected(true);

                v.setBackgroundResource(R.color.pressed_color);

            }

        }
    });
```

Comment: Add a listener to the listview not to the row

Comment: Did that but now it's its always returned false for "IsSelected()"

Answer (score 1):

Set `listView.onItemClicklistener` instead of `row.setOnClickListener`
like this:

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int position,
                                    long id) {


                                }
                        });
```

Comment: I'm using a custom ListAdapter, that where I am listening for the row click, so i cant use setOnItemClickListener on the Listview

Comment: you don't need to listen for the row click if you set onItemClickListener where you can get the posistion of the item the user clicked.

Comment: See my edit above, now it always returns false for "isselected"

Comment: so you want to return false if item clicked twice ??